# Why i get infinity loop when i update object by setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying change class name by using library classname.
And i got problem when update my object data for save state of className.
I am sure not problem with library classname. Some one can help me ?

```
    export default function Sidebar() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState({
        home: false,
        category: false,
        product: false,
        order: false,
    });
    const handleActive = (name) => {
        setActive({
            ...active,
            [name]: !active[name],
        });
    };
    return (
        <Col md={2} id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li className={classNames({ active: active.home })} onClick={handleActive("home")}>
                    <NavLink to={`/home`}> Home </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className={classNames({ active: active.category })} onClick={handleActive("category")}>
                    <NavLink to={`/category`}> Category </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className={classNames({ active: active.product })} onClick={handleActive("product")}>
                    <NavLink to={`/product`}> Product </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className={classNames({ active: active.order })} onClick={handleActive("order")}>
                    <NavLink to={`/order`}> Order </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </Col>
    );
}
```

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PROBLEM

You're calling the function directly  here `onClick={handleActive("order")}` which triggers the multiple re-renders.
What you're saying to the code here is let's call the onClick handler whenever the component mounts.

## SOLUTION

`() => handleActive("home")` assign a function to the onClick handlers like this.
What you're saying to the code here is I'm assigning a function to the onClick handlers, call the function whenever someone clicks on the element.

```
<li className={classNames({ active: active.home })} onClick={() => handleActive("home")}>
    <NavLink to={`/home`}> Home </NavLink>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks you, i am used to use `onClick={handleClick}` and now know it different `onClick={handleClick()}`

Comment: @Cyan In your case you are providing as reference, so it will re render infinitely. When you make in arrow function it will works.